# \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}

Tags: graphics, errors

I have this error when I try to insert a figure, even if I insert just the

```
\begin{figure}

\end{figure}
```

with nothing inside. 
What might be happening?
I use the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{styles/xthesis} %Thesis Style
\usepackage{styles/xtocinc} %Include Table of Contents as the first entry in TOC
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
```

and am using the Thesis sample that already comes with the WinEdt for windows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimally working example or your file, which produces the error. In your case, I suspect a missing `\begin{figure}` or an accidental `%` character.

Comment: before adding the figure, could the file be processed successfully, without any messages at the end of the log file indicating that it ended at some level other than 0?  if it did, that means you have `\begin` and `\end` statments out of phase, or the number of open braces doesn't match the number of close braces.  get rid of those problems first.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really give any information in your question, you should always give a *complete* small document that reproduces the problem. However you document will have 
code equivalent to the following. If you have a `\begin{figure}` in the source, an earlier error or misplaced command will have prevented it being executed. Note you should *only* consider the first error, if you get an error before the one you mention, just fix the first, later errors are often spurious.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\eat[1]{\bgroup}
\begin{document}


\eat
\begin{figure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \end{figure}

?
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah after asking five years of this question, today I face same issue. When I used `xcolor` or `colortbl`, I faced same error. Thanks to @Mauramz whose answer here gives me hint and I figure out error which comes because of `xthesis` package, then I found solution of this problem here [LaTex error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/fApDhlr5ko8)

The error was in `xthesis.sty` file. Just after commenting the code below, error has gone.

```
% Redefine the macro used for floats (including figures and tables)
% so that single spacing is used.
% (Note \def\figure{\@float{figure}set single spacing} doesn't work
%  because figure has an optional argument)
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
            {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
             \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
             \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
             \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
     }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
    \boxmaxdepth\z@
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}
```

Thanks to user.nokia.com who resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain what caused the problem here?

Comment: Just comment the whole code, I have mentioned, no effect will be taken and error will be resolved. I don't know the background exactly why this code but it was a solution. If you are facing the same issue, just follow the instruction and may it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

@user52326 I made this `MWE` up and make it works, I will let it here so you can check your versión. I eliminated the `xthesis` and `xtocinc`, because I don't have the `.sty` files.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[hb]
  \centering
  \caption[Close up of \textit{Hemidactylus} sp.]
   {Close up of \textit{Hemidactylus} sp., which is
   part the genus of the gecko family. It is the
   second most speciose genus in the family.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output
[image: The Output]

Comment: I have same error, when I removes xthesis, it works but how I can tackle this as xthesis is important for me?